# How to connect AzureDevOps TFVS in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, azure, tfs

is there a way to connect TFVS in Visual Studio Code since Github private repository can only be shared  for 3 persons.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is,

**Install TFS extention**

1. Open VS Code
2. Go to Extentions
3. Look for TFS
4. Install it

add the following entry to Settings (File > Preferences > Settings

```
tfs.location": "<path-to-tf-command-line>
```

for more details: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/java/vscode-extension?view=azure-devops

et voilà !